# Is there a similar command in VSC like "run App" in RStudio?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, shiny, rstudio

I am working with R in Visual Studio Code, which is usually working fine. To start my Shiny app I used: `(source("app.R"))`

Until yesterday, this worked fine, just as "run App" button in RStudio, but now I get some different behavior in some lines of code of my app leading to an error. What is working in VSC is to run all line of "app.R" in a sequence separately.

Is there a similar command or button in VSC like the "run App" button in RStudio?

Comment: What if you use `shiny::runApp("app.R")` instead of `source()`?

Comment: Finally, I found time to test. It works, much appreciated. 

Do you know why that is? Where is the difference?

Comment: I don't know. But I do know that `runApp()` is specifically designed to launch shiny apps, whereas `source()` working before might have been a happy incident more than anything else.